# Fast way to read and merge multiple csv files on GCP Cloud Storage

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, python-itertools

I've got a lot of csv files on my cloud storage and I want to create a Cloud Functions to read multiples files. Currently I'm able to get the file list with the function *list_blobs_with_prefix*, read multiple csv files and merge them with pd.concat , however it's pretty slow.

```
file_list = list_blobs_with_prefix(
            bucket_name=bucket_name, prefix=prefix + date_timestamp
        )
file_list = ["gs://" + bucket_name + "/" + row for row in file_list]

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in file_list])
```

So I've tried to use the *convtools* library:

```
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

file_list = list_blobs_with_prefix(
            bucket_name=bucket_name, prefix=prefix + date_timestamp
        )
file_list = ["gs://" + bucket_name + "/" + row for row in file_list]

table = None
for files in file_list:
   table_ = Table.from_csv(files, header=True)
   if table is None:
      table = table_
   else:
      table.chain(table_)
iterable_dict = table.into_iter_rows(dict)
df = pd.DataFrame(list(iterable_dict))
```

However I'm getting the error that the files do not exist and I'm stuck with that. Any ideas on how to fix this or a better approach ?

Comment: Your code must download the file first before Pandas can read it. This line will not work `pd.read_csv(f)`. Pandas does not understand the scheme `gs://`.

Comment: I wrote that. Does it help? https://medium.com/google-cloud/merge-clean-transform-your-csvs-easily-with-bigquery-3a73c0c26d57

Comment: `Table.from_csv` method supports local files or anything `csv.reader` understands

Comment: @JohnHanley the `pd.read_csv(f)` works fine. The problem is that it's too slow

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I've read your article but I don't think it solves my problem since my csv files are generated every minute.

Comment: Pandas does not directly support Google Cloud Storage. That means you are using some other application to manage Cloud Storage. You have left out that detail.